# why does in HTTP basic authentication window pop up multiple times even after I enter wrong credentials?

Tags: php, http, basic-authentication

I am trying to implement HTTP basic authentication in my website. The code is given below. When I request the protected resource I get a window that asks for username and password. Why does authentication window pop up when I enter wrong credentials? I know to use a counter and then redirect the users after they reach a limit. But what I don't understand is why the window pops up again. Am I missing something?

```
  <?php
$LoginSuccessful = false;

// Check username and password:

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){

    $Username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $Password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    if ($Username == 'jonas' && $Password == 'foobar'){
        $LoginSuccessful = true;
    }
}

// Login passed successful?

if (!$LoginSuccessful){
 /* 
** The user gets here if:
** 
** 1. The user entered incorrect login data
**     --> User will see the error message from below
**
** 2. Or the user requested the page for the first time
**     --> Then the 401 headers apply and the "login box" will
**         be shown
*/


    // The text inside the realm section will be visible for the 
    // user in the login box
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secret page"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

    print "Login failed!\n";

}
else {

    // The user entered the correct login data, put
    // your confidential data in here: 

    print 'you reached the secret page!';
}
?>
```

Comment: You say the answer in the comments. It goes through the same code whether it's the first visit or after a login failure. You specifically tell them they have to log in again, just to see your "login failed" message.